# How to get the username and Discord tag of the owner of server - Python

Tags: python, permissions, discord, discord.py

I'm looking for a method in the discord.py library to return the owner of the server the bot has been deployed in. Right now I just have it hard coded (i.e.

```
if message.content == '!owner': 
    await message.channel.send('ownername#1234')
```

), but when the owner changes their name I have to change it, and it seems like a hassle for nothing. I've looked into the permissions system of discord.py but it doesn't seem to have something that does this. Is there anything that does this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [`Guild.owner`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.owner)

```
await message.channel.send(str(message.guild.owner))
```

Comment: God, thank you so much for this. I've been looking everywhere but i don't have the patience to read through documentation.

Comment: would it be possible to return the server nickname?

Comment: Sure, `Guild.owner` is a `Member` so you can use `message.guild.owner.display_name`