# How can i get the server owner name in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, owner

I use: await ctx.send(str(ctx.guild.owner.id)) or await ctx.send(ctx.guild.owner.id) but the bot say 'None'. How can i fix this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the username and Discord tag of the owner of server - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741196/how-to-get-the-username-and-discord-tag-of-the-owner-of-server-python)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get a `discord.Member` object instead of a string object. To do this, you can use the `get_member` function. Here is a simple function to output the server's owner to the channel:

```
@client.command()
async def owner_find(ctx):
    guild_owner = client.get_user(int(ctx.guild.owner.id))
    await ctx.send(f'The owner of this server is: {guild_owner}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need intents in order to get the member's info. Since `ctx.guild.owner` is `discord.Member` object. You need member intents.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents= discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

You also need to turn on intents from discord developer portal.

[Reference (With guide on how to enable intents)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)

P.S: Running command in DMs also returns `None`.